# Is it good for performance to transfer column to own table?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table with about 10 columns. One of the columns is a varchar(255). The typical values in this column have a length of about 50 - 80 characters.
These values are very often the same. This means there are about 100 values which can be in this column (no null values). The table has about 1 million entries. In the select statement I fetch big amounts of rows of the table.

Is it a good idea to make an own table for this ~ 100 values and reference to them with a foreign key in the "main table"?

I mean, sure it takes less space to save this values, when i create a new table for them, but is it good regarding to performance?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance (as long as properly indexed.)

Comment: Find a good article on "database normalization", it'll give you an understanding on this subject and where it's appropriate to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to maintain it in a separate table and refer them with a foreign key in the main table. Main table should be properly indexed as well.

The advantage of maintaining it in separate table is that if there is a change in the value, you need not go to the main table (~ 1 million entries) and replace it everywhere instead go to the new table and make the changes in one place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, this is a big advantage, but in my case this values  probably will not get updated ever.

Comment: Regarding the performance with joins, indexes on foreign keys can provide performance benefits for table joins involving the primary and foreign key

Answer (score 0):

I would say 'no' for performance reasons. Every join costs, and costs more if you have one million records to join.

Another thing you can do is to use a numeric value representing those common texts, and use a Enum (or a similar structure) to translate those numbers into text in your favourite language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, but my consideration was, if it is faster because there are lots of equal values, which are fetched and maybe the performance benefit of this is bigger than the costs of these joins.

Answer (score 0):

Tables don't have performance. Queries have performance.

It *might* be good for performance of certain queries to change the way you store your data. For other queries, it might harm performance. It depends on the queries you run against the data.

You won't know for sure until you test and measure the performance of your queries using both methods of storage.

Sorry for this non-answer, but I'm trying to discourage the mindset of guessing at performance characteristics without enough information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand your point. But the query, which I am talking about, fetches all columns and the question is if it's better in performance to fetch directly the value multiple times or fetch this value with a JOIN. But probably you are right, the best would be to test it and measure the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I there are 4 things that you need to consider here.

- How would you maintain it?
  You say there are many repeated values, how would you make sure even if you decide to move it to a different table, that you will end up with no duplicates? Would you search for similar entries and then decide if you need to create a new one or reuse an existing one? Just something you need to think about.
- Performance inserting?
  If you are not doing any search on that text field? (and if you do may actually consider a full text search option).
  If you move this to a different table, you indeed add an additional index to your table, this means that during insert time it will have a penalty, so, if inserting time is more important to you, then you may actually consider just leaving the text where it is right now.
- Performance reading?
  If you care more about the reading time, again if you don't search through those text in the query then adding an external table would add additional search and comparisons and more work to find all the data. So, leaving it where it is will be just fine.
- Size
  If you are worry about size of data, then yes, you may move this to a different table and try to reduce repeated ones to save space.